# sum hash values inside db column and place result in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table called google_records in which every row is a snapshot of a google adwords account for that day.

Here is the schema -

```
create_table "google_records", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "user_id"
  t.string   "date"
  t.text     "stats"
  t.text     "account_name"
  t.datetime "created_at",                                                        :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                                                        :null => false
  t.decimal  "total_cost",        :precision => 12, :scale => 2, :default => 0.0, :null => false
  t.integer  "total_conversions",                                :default => 0,   :null => false
end

add_index "google_records", ["date"], :name => "index_google_records_on_date"
```

`stats` contains a hash of the day's stats by campaign and an entry would look something like this:

```
:Carpet Cleaning:
 :conversions: 3
 :cost: 391.47
:Upholstery Cleaning:
 :conversions: 0
 :cost: 69.96
:Air Duct Cleaning:
 :conversions: 0
 :cost: 8.68
```

I just added those `total_cost` and `total_conversion` columns and I'd like to update those with the totals for each respective value each day.

I can get the total I want to work in my console like so(the cost total doesn't match up with the sample I gave but its only because I shortened the sample to fit better - the total is correct) -

```
user = User.find(6)
GoogleRecord.where(user_id: user).where(date: "20140328").map {|m| m.stats}.map{ |s| s.map{ |key,        value| value[:cost] || 0 } }.map {|m| m.inject(:+)}.compact.reduce(&:+)
=> 660.26
```

I'd like to update all records in the table this way for conversions and cost and save them but when I try something like:

```
GoogleRecord.all.each do |g|
  g.map {|m| m.stats}.map{ |s| s.map{ |key, value| value[:cost] || 0 } }.map {|m| m.inject(:+)}.compact.reduce(&:+)
end
```

I keep getting `NoMethodError: undefined method map for GoogleRecord:0x5f09868`

It seems like since I'm just grabbing one record in the example that is working, I should be able to apply code to `each` record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your example code, what the where method return is something like array, so map can work. But inside the GoogleRecord.all.each block, the g is reference to the db record. Remove the first map call, and see whether it will work.

```
GoogleRecord.all.each do |g|
  g.stats.map{ |s| s.map{ |key, value| value[:cost] || 0 } }.map {|m| m.inject(:+)}.compact.reduce(&:+)
end
```

Comment: yup - been working with one too many map calls today and couldn't see it.  Thanks!